# Can someone give me an example of an example of a class hierarchy relevant to computer science?

Tags: class-design

Can someone give me an example of an example of a class hierarchy relevant to computer science?

In my lectures I've seen some simple examples like:

## Vehicle

### Construction

#### Heavy

Machinery

Crane

Grader

Back-hoe

#### Haulage

Semi-trailer

Flatbed

### Passenger

#### Commercial

Bus

Fire-truck

Limousine

Police-motorcycle

#### Personal

Car

SUV

Motorcycle

Comment: How is that not relevant to computer science? :)

Comment: Computer language family tree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a class hierarchy from a content management system I work on:

- Node

  - User

    - Active Directory User
    - Database User
  - Folder

    - Site
    - Template Gallery
    - Image Gallery
  - Template
  - Page
  - File

Answer (score 2):

A decent example from the .NET world (and I believe Java has something very similar) might be:

- Exception

  - ArgumentException

    - ArgumentNullException
    - ArgumentOutOfRangeException
  - ArithmeticException

    - DivideByZeroException
    - NotFiniteNumberException
    - OverflowException
  - IOException

    - DirectoryNotFoundException
    - FileNotFoundException
    - PathTooLongException

...etc., etc.

(The hierarchy is actually **much** bigger than that; those are just some popular examples.)